# Sitecore media upload not finishing after 7.2 SP2 upgrade

Tags: sitecore

we recently upgraded from Sitecore 7.2 initial version to the SP2 one. The upgrade went fine and everthing seemed to be working. However, we noticed that when trying to upload files through the (new) media library, the upload never finishes. I can see a 404 request to http://xx/api/sitecore/media/upload in the console, but I can't figure out what is missing. I have checked that I have the correct dll versions, and also use fresh config files for Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config.

The upgrade went fine and I have republished/reindexed everything.

Does anyone have any hints on what could be missing?

Comment: do you have any error on logs file?

Comment: Do you have any custom 404 handlers in your solution? It may not be ignoring the api path correctly.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber No error, but a debug line saying: DEBUG Unable to parse product url 'http://xxxx/api/sitecore/Media/Upload'.

Comment: @jammykam No custom 404 handlers. It goes to the standard sitecore 404 page "The requested document was not found"

Comment: <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
do you have above setting inside : encodeNameReplacements  configuration.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber I do, yes

Comment: Does the media item name have dashes in it then? Try to upload one without any dashes.

Comment: I have tried several files, including files with and without dashes and of different formats (gif, jpeg, png). I don't think thats the problem. The problem is that the api url can't be resolved or that some item doesn't exist.

Comment: please remove that configuration. I know it was a bug in some version of sitecore.

Comment: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/998758 maybe this patch will help you. I am not sure about it, but I know I met your problem

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Thanks, but the patch didn't help. Neither did removing the configuration line..

Comment: Do you have any custom routing for your own Web API?

Comment: @JonathanRobbins No, no other use of Web API in the solution.

Comment: I suggest you to open a support ticket.

Comment: Yes, I have created one. Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If you have created custom routes or WebAPI, change your custom API route defination from api to xxxapi or anyother name as you need. Because Sitecore has it's own API which has /api/ as route and if you create custom routes with same name, Sitecore's request will go to custom api route not to Sitecore's one.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Change to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "xxxapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: There are no custom web api's configured, actually.